# viewport render has better anti-aliasing than output render

Tags: grease-pencil, antialiasing

[image: anti aliasing fail]

This screen grab has my viewport render on the left and output on the right. Can anyone help me solve why my lines are so poor on the output image?

this is a 3d model with a grease pencil outline and I'm rendering with cycles

Comment: What resolution are you rendering at?

Comment: We could use a screen shot of your render settings but I suspect @James question is the key.  That looks like a very low resolution render.

Comment: You're 100% correct. it was a low res render. Thanks for the help